# how to run Laravel Downloaded project from Cpanel on my local computer

Tags: laravel

when I run command

```
php artisan serve
```

it runs server and seems to be working properly. it show message

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Wed Sep 15 11:33:05 2021] PHP 8.0.8 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

but when I go to google and try http://127.0.0.1:8000 it shows error

```
Warning: require(C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\public/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\public/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\public\index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\server.php(21): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Muhammad Adnan\Downloads\school\public\index.php on line 24
```

I tried my best to placing index.php and server.php in public folder.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: code is downloaded from Cpanel. I think the error is about production mode to local conversion issue related.

Comment: "_but when I go to google and try http://127.0.0.1:8000_" What does that mean? When you search google? `127.0.0.1` is your local IP, not reachable from outside

Comment: Since `/vendor/autoload.php` seems to be missing, did you install all dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Change `APP_ENV` to local

```
APP_ENV=local
```

Change `APP_DEBUG` to true & Set `APP_URL` to localhost

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Update you Database connection

Then install all dependencies

```
composer install
```

Finally start the server

```
php artisan serve
```